# How to add administrator's name and phone in admin table and at the same time add branch_name in admin table from branch table with stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables

```
Branch (Branch_No, Branch_Name)
Admin (Admin_No, Admin_Name,Admin_Phone,Branch_No)
```

Branch table should have the following values

```
Branch_No     Branch_Name
1             Inala
2             Richlands
3             Forest Lake
```

Now, I want to register a new admin by assigning him into a specific branch by selecting the branch_name from branch table.

In order to make it more clear, If I want to register a new admin this is what I want to do

```
Enter Admin_Name: Raef
Enter Admin_Phone: 01711182097
Choose your Branch: Richlands [This value will be selected from Branch table]
```

After completing registration, I would like to see the following output below by using SELECT * FROM Admin :

```
Admin_No Admin_Name Admin_Phone Branch_No
1        Raef       01711182097  2
```

I want to get this above final result, after selecting a branch_name = 'Richlands' while registering the new admin. And I want to achieve this result through SQL Server Stored Procedure.

Now this what I have done so far:

First I created the Branch table and inserted values

```
CREATE TABLE Branch
(Branch_No INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 Branch_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
 )

INSERT INTO Branch (Branch_Name)
VALUES('Inala')
INSERT INTO Branch (Branch_Name)
VALUES('Richlands')
INSERT INTO Branch (Branch_Name)
VALUES ('Forest Lake')
```

And then I created Admin table

```
CREATE TABLE Admin
(Admin_No INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 Admin_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 Admin_Phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 Branch_No INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Branch(Branch_No)
 )
```

Then I created a stored procedure for registering a new admin.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddAdmin
@AdminNo INTEGER OUTPUT,
@AdminName VARCHAR(50),
@AdminPhone VARCHAR(20),
@BranchName VARCHAR(20),
@BranchNo INTEGER OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SET @AdminNo = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO Admin (Branch_No)
SELECT Branch.Branch_No FROM Branch,Admin
WHERE Branch.Branch_No = Admin.Branch_No
AND Branch_Name = @BranchName

INSERT INTO Admin (Admin_Name,Admin_Phone)
VALUES (@AdminName,@AdminPhone)
END
```

Stored Procedure was created successfully

Then I tried executing the stored procedure in order register a new admin

```
EXECUTE AddAdmin 'Raef','01711182097','Richlands'
```

And I got the following error message:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure AddAdmin, Line 41
Error converting data type varchar to int.
```

I am almost certain there is a mistake in my logic syntax in the stored procedure that I have created. 
It would be really helpful for me if the stored procedure logic syntax is fixed.

Comment: I don't think `SET @AdminNo = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is going to have anything in it as it doesn't have an `INSERT` before it.  Something doesn't seem right.

Comment: Ewwww... Old join syntax. You might benefit from learning the "new" syntax (it's 20 years old)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to insert Admin number as you have set it to identity, this is what i would do if i were in your shoes wearing your clothes and working on your computer:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddAdmin
    @AdminName VARCHAR(50),
    @AdminPhone VARCHAR(20),
    @BranchName VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Admin (Admin_Name, Admin_Phone, Branch_No)
    SELECT @AdminName, @AdminPhone, (Select Branch_No from Branch where Branch_Name = @BranchName)
END
```

Please try this and give me feedback, I can't run SQL Server at the moment so i can't be sure if i made a mistake somewhere!

Comment: "if i were in your shoes wearing your clothes and working on your computer" <-- that's a very creepy scenario...

Comment: @Zack I'm a ghost, that's what i do XD

Comment: @Tonner Maan ... I tested your code and it worked successfully ... After executing the procedure with input parameters I'm getting the desired result that I want ... Really appreciate it :)

Comment: @beginIT i'm really glad i could help ^__^